# Ansible not picking up custom module

Tags: module, ansible

I'm having issues with Ansible picking up a module that I've added.

1. The module is called 'passwordstore' https://github.com/morphje/ansible_pass_lookup/.
2. I'm using Ansible 2.2
3. In my playbook, I've added a 'library' folder and have added the contents of that GitHub directory to that folder. I've also tried uncommenting `library        = /usr/share/ansible/modules` and adding the module files there and still doesn't get picked up.
4. Have also tried setting environment variable to `ANSIBLE_LIBRARY=/usr/share/ansible/modules`

My Ansible playbook looks like this:

```
---

- name: example play
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: set password
      debug: msg="{{ lookup('passwordstore', 'files/test create=true')}}"
```

And when I run this I get this error;

ansible-playbook main.yml

```
PLAY [example play] ******************************************************

TASK [set password] ************************************************************
fatal: [backend.example.name]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "lookup plugin (passwordstore) not found"}
fatal: [mastery.example.name]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "lookup plugin (passwordstore) not found"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/etc/ansible/roles/test-role/main.retry
```

Any guidance on what I'm missing? It may just be the way in which I'm trying to add the custom module, but any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a lookup plugin (not a module), so it should go into a directory named `lookup_plugins` (not `library`).

Alternatively, add the path to the cloned repository in `ansible.cfg` using the [`lookup-plugins` setting](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#lookup-plugins).